# Inject service at runtime angular

Tags: angularjs, runtime, inject

How do I inject a service at runtime?

Use case:

URL has a variable 'object' which can be either customer/user/item. The view is always the same, the controller is always the same only the service changes based on the url parameter value of 'object'

So when you access http://www.application.com/?object=user it should load the generic view+controller but inject the service at runtime.

Comment: Check out the architectural pattern named Factory Pattern

Comment: you can change config with a serviceProvider